# Linux languages/tools specific for log parsing

Tags: parsing, logging

Is there such a thing? Maybe like Microsoft's LogParser?

I know there's `sed/awk`, but I'm curious if there are any specific tools or even programming languages.

PS: I'm not sure this belongs here or on SF.

Answer (score 1):

Grep. And really, for text-processing utilities, perl is unmatched.

Answer (score 1):

For text parsing, the shell is generally all you need.

sed/awk/grep/tr/more/less/find/sort/etc are a very powerful suite of tools that will probably do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just related but *awstats* parses all apache logs in Linux to make its statistics.